# Do Spectral Blades - Healing Blades get a bonus penalty in inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm considering trying out a melee wizard build for Inferno (now that monsters in acts 3/4 don't hit quite as massively!) but was wondering one thing...

I know that Lifesteal (weapons with 2.5% damage turned into life) gets an 80% penalty (IE. it's only 20% effective) in inferno difficulty to curb the potential invulnerability from the stat early on like D2 had.

I was wondering if the wizard skill Spectral Blades with the rune Healing Blades (on a crit, get 8% of the damage back as life) gets this same penalty, or can I be sure to get that full 8% returned?

If it takes an 80% penalty it's totally not worth it.  But if it doesn't it looks promising.

Comment: afaik all life steal % gets a penalty

Comment: Agree with @yx., and also note that wizards don't get passive 30% damage reduction unlike melee classes.

Comment: Melee wizard requires a little thinking outside the box for inferno. [try this critical mass build](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/vfgjq/critical_mass_melee_tanky_wizard_act_2_inferno/) which focuses on rapidly resetting defensive cooldowns by creative critting.

Comment: While they do not get the built in 30%, the 20% reduction to melee from blur helps a lot.  I have a friend whose melee wizard can tank comfortably using blades into Act 2 and moderately in Act 3 still.  Note that Archon's damage reduction synergizes well. Energy armor is probably a must for this build, as well as diamond shield. Just my thoughts. You will want +All Resist gear, and lots of it.

Answer (score 1):

It penalties, you're better of going for Life on Hit. [Here is some life on hit tables for various Wizard spells and runes that may help.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149154265)